# Closing popup with button in child usercontrol

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, parent-child, uwp

I'm dealing with a popup which has a usercontrol as a child. This is done in a XAML file in UWP using Visual Studio 2015. 
 In my usercontrol resides a button with which I would like to close the parenting popup. I can't seem to achieve this - I've tried several options and the closest was by using a relay command. It should be mentioned that the popup pops up as supposed to. 
Here is the [popup with usercontrol child.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PsCD.png) No namespace problems, since the popup is working. 
Here is the [button in the usercontrol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nHal.png)

What should my approach be? I'm using ViewModels (MVVM desing) for this, and both usercontrol have access to the same instance of a ViewModel class.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx . You bind the Popup.IsOpen to a property in your view model ... the button sets the property to false.

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding ViewModel.IsOpen}" >
  ...
</Popup>
```

In the ViewModel you define a command that you can attach to AddCriteria button as such:

```
private ICommand _AddCriteriaCommand;
  public ICommand AddCriteriaCommand
  {
     get
     {
        return _AddCriteriaCommand;
     }
     set
     {
        _AddCriteriaCommand = value;
     }
  }
```

And you initiate this command in the constructor or the getter of AddCriteriaCommand to a RelayCommand... as such

```
public VMConstructor(...)
{
    _AddCriteriaCommand = new RelayCommand(execute => ClosePopup(), canExecute => true);
}

private void ClosePopup()
{
   _IsOpen = false;
}
```

in your xaml assign the commadn to the AddCriteria button , something like

```
<local:AddCrteria Command="{Binding AddCriteriaCommand}" />
```

For the popup you simply create a property for it with change notification as such:

```
private bool _isOpen;
public bool IsOpen
{
  get { return _isOpen; }
  set
  {
    if (_isOpen == value) return;
    _isOpen = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpen");
  }
}
```

and finally bind the IsOpen property of the Popup control to that of the ViewModel as such:

```
IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"
```

And that should be it ... good luck.

Comment: This seems neat. I can't seem to do it right, though.
Now none of my xaml files recognize my ViewModel. 
How is this property made - I think I'm doing something wrong..
<code>
public bool _addCriteriaIsOpen;
        public bool AddCriteriaIsOpen
        {
            get { return _addCriteriaIsOpen; }
            set
            {
                _addCriteriaIsOpen = !_addCriteriaIsOpen;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks a bunch! RaisePropertyChanged can't be called, though - I'm working in UWP and not WPF so I'm going with OnPropertyChanged().

Comment: I am not familiar with UWP but some concepts should be the same, Good luck.

Comment: It worked like a charm when RaisePropertyChanged were changed to OnPropertyChanged. Thanks again, I'll mark as answer.